# How to extract a number from a string in a particular format?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a String like this as shown below. From below string I need to extract number `123` and it can be at any position as shown below but there will be only one number in a string and it will always be in the same format `_number_`

```
text_data_123
text_data_123_abc_count
text_data_123_abc_pqr_count

text_tery_qwer_data_123
text_tery_qwer_data_123_count
text_tery_qwer_data_123_abc_pqr_count
```

Below is the code:

```
String value = "text_data_123_abc_count";   

// this below code will not work as index 2 is not a number in some of the above example
int textId = Integer.parseInt(value.split("_")[2]);
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You should define "best". You could use a regexp or a removal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) magic:

```
String value = "text_data_123_abc_count";
Integer id = Ints.tryParse(CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9').retainFrom(value)
```

see also [`CharMatcher` doc](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher)

Answer (score 1):

```
\\d+
```

this regex with `find` should do it for you.

Comment: @ThaNet: This is Java, not C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use Positive lookahead assertion.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=_)\\d+(?=_)").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) 
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceAll` to remove all non-digits to leave only one number (since you say there will be only 1 number in the input string):

```
String s = "text_data_123_abc_count".replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/E2MyGX)

Instead of `[^0-9]` you can use `\D` (which also means *non-digit*):

```
String s = "text_data_123_abc_count".replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Given current requirements and restrictions, the `replaceAll` solution seems the most convenient (no need to use `Matcher` directly).

Answer (score 0):

u can get all parts from that string and compare with its UPPERCASE, if it is equal then u can parse it to a number and save:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String txt = "text_tery_qwer_data_123_abc_pqr_count";

    String[] words = txt.split("_");

    int num = 0;

    for (String t : words) {
        if(t == t.toUpperCase())
            num = Integer.parseInt(t);
    }

    System.out.println(num);
}
```

}

Comment: This will fail in case there is a word in ALLCAPS.

Comment: then u can edit the if: if(t == t.toUpperCase() && t == t.toLowerCase()) all is part of the imagination...